# Calendar control is not popping-up when clicked on image

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, calendarextender

I'm using a `CalendarExtender` control with the help of `<img>` to populate a `TextBox` with a date. I am using this in `EditItemTemplate` of `GridView`. But when I click on the image, the calendar control is not poping up.

I have used this `CalendarExtender` control in four or five other places (in this project) also. Everywhere else it is working fine. I have compared the code from the well working version to this code. No difference at all.

I have written the code like below:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateDelivered" runat="server" 
                 Text='<%# Bind("DateDelivered","{0:dd/MM/yy}") %>' 
                 CssClass="DateTextBoxInGridView" >
    </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="calexDateDelivered" runat="server" 
                          Format="dd/MM/yy" 
                          TargetControlID="txtDateDelivered"
                          PopupButtonID="calDateDelivered">
    </asp:CalendarExtender>
    <img src="Images/calendar.gif" 
         id="calDateDelivered" 
         alt="Calendar" />
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Can anybody please tell where could be the problem?

Comment: how many row do you have in grid? also probably you have more than one image with such id

Comment: You are right Samich. Thank you very much. One more doubt - Now, the calendar is coming so ugly,i.e. with awkward horizontal rules inside the calendar. How can I format the calendar to make it look neat?

Comment: Forget about it :) It's good that you solve your problem

Comment: Hi Samich, I am getting the calendar, but with the awkward horizontal lines. How can I format the calendar to make it look neat? PLEASE HELP ME ON THIS.

Comment: @Ashok kumar Ask a new question, try to include a screen shop of your calendar.

Comment: @Samich You should re enter your comment as an answer so it could be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

how many row do you have in grid? also probably you have more than one image with such id

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Actually it was the answer. If you check the comments under question you can find that the problem was exactly with multiple control with the same Id. I've just reposted comment as an answer to allow to accept the answer on the question for OP.

Answer (score 0):

The image tag which you have used is not a server control.
It is simple html control, this is the reason why the calender control does not reconise this image control..

Try using asp.net image button over here instead of .
It should work then.

cheers....

Rahul C.