# CalendarExtender from AjaxControlToolKit.Dll Doesn't 'Pop Up' When Upgrading/Updating to Latest Dll Version

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asp.net-4.0, calendarextender

I have a form that formerly used assembly version 1.0.10301.0 of the AjaxControlToolKit.Dll and when upgrading to newer versions such as 4.1.7.607, the CalendarExtender object stops working in that the calendar button no longer creates a drop down-esque selection object. Nothing has changed in my code, only the Third Party dll as it jumped from 764KB to ~6.5MB.

The issue seems to be that if there is more than one image with the same ID (I have three), this issue occurs. Source: [Calendar control is not popping-up when clicked on image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467362/calendar-control-is-not-popping-up-when-clicked-on-image)

Because of the dynamic way in which the actual form is created, it is impossible for me to 'hardcode' several instances of CalendarExtender in the .ascx and call them in the .cs so as to prevent this issue; eg I can only have this dateCal. Is there a way to resolve this issue that will still allow me to upgrade to the latest version of the Dll such as some sort of flag that allows for multiple instances of the same ID?

**Code:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="DateTb.ascx.cs" Inherits="DateTb" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajx" %>
<asp:TextBox ID="dateTb" runat="server" Width="125px" MaxLength="1000"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:image id="dateImg" runat="server" imageurl="~/images/calendar.png" />
<ajx:CalendarExtender ID="dateCal"  runat="server" PopupButtonID="dateImg" TargetControlID="dateTb"></ajx:CalendarExtender>

<asp:CompareValidator id="dateValidator" runat="server" Type="Date" Operator="DataTypeCheck" ControlToValidate="dateTb" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid date." ValidationGroup="validate"  Text="*" > </asp:CompareValidator>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="dateRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="dateTb" Text="*" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid date." ValidationGroup="validate"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

**Form Pre-DLL 'Upgrade':**

[image: Correct]

**Form Post-DLL 'Upgrade':**

[image]

Comment: How did you update your ajax control toolkit? From codeplex? Nuget?

Comment: Could you post the code that is dynamically creating the controls?

Comment: @Garrison Neely The dynamic process is long and complex, but the code that creates the control is `control = (DateTb)LoadControl("~/Form_Controls/DateTb.ascx");` where control is System.Web.UI.Control object. I would like to point out this control creation has not changed at all, only the .Dll